# Capturing window Qt 6.5

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt6, qtmultimedia

Qt 6.5 introduced `ScreenCapture` class which should record a screen.
Check an [example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtmultimedia-screencapture.html#details)

I've tried the following:

```
ApplicationWindow {
  id: root

  MouseArea {
    id: recording
    anchors.fill: parent
    property bool inProcess: false
    onClicked: {
      if (recording.inProcess) {
        screenCapture.active = recording.inProcess = false;
        recorder.stop();  
      } else {
        screenCapture.active = recording.inProcess = true;
        recorder.record();
      }
    }
  }

  CaptureSession {
    id: captureSession
    screenCapture: ScreenCapture {
      id: screenCapture
      active: false
    }
    recorder: MediaRecorder {
      id: recorder
      mediaFormat {
        fileFormat: MediaFormat.MPEG4
        videoCodec: MediaFormat.VideoCodec.H265
      }
      outputLocation: "desired-name.mp4"
      quality: MediaRecorder.HighQuality
    }
  }
}
```

And thats work!

But then I wanted to capture a window, not a whole screen.
Due to [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtmultimedia-screencapture.html#window-prop), `ScreenCapture` has a `window` property to achieve that, but when I add
`window: root` to it, I got an error: `Cannot assign to non-existent property "window"`

Is it bug in Qt 6.5 or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, Qt6.5.0 has removed it because of bugs.